# Is it possible to use Google Adsense in a free Azure Web App (azurewebsites.net)?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, adsense

A free Azure Web App means the URL for the app will be:

```
  https://[name].azurewebsites.net
```

And, if I'm correct, according to Google Adsense rules you need to enable Adsense for the root domain (in this case: "`azurewebsites.net`")

**Question:** is it possible somehow to enable Google Adsense in this scenario? and how? If not, are there good alternatives?

Context is I have a small app that is free to use for anyone and I see that this app is used regularly and maybe I could profit a little with it. (The app is just a xml to pdf converter)

Answer (score 0):

> if I'm correct, according to Google Adsense rules you need to enable Adsense for the root domain (in this case: "azurewebsites.net")azurewebsites.net

We are not the owner of the root domain, so we can't do anything with this domain.  But I haven't found this rule on Google Adsense site. So you can just following the steps on Google Adsense home page. Create a new account, input your site information and input your personal information.

https://www.google.com/adsense/start/#/?modal_active=none

You could fill the website URL with "http://[yoursitename].azurewebsites.net".

[image]

After these steps, we will get a html code. We can fill this html code after the <head> tag of our root page in your web application.